# How to set PrimeNG theme?

Tags: angular, primeng

I am finding some problem trying to understand how to set the PrimeNG theme. If I go here:
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/crud

I can see that the theme set by default is the **bootstrap4-light-blue**.

Ok, how can I set this theme in my project? I am using PrimeNG but I can't find themes into my project.

Have I to install in some way? What am I missing?

**EDIT-1:** Into the folder of PrimeNg themes of my foler
(/home/developer/Documents/Angular-WS/color_patch/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes) I only find these few themes? why? It seems to me that a lot of themes is missing. Isn't it?
In particular the themes related to BootStrap seems to be not present

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the them now that displayed are new themes base of primeng 10 and currently still in development at the time of writing this answer *`(PrimeNG 10.0.0-rc.4-SNAPSHOT by PrimeTek)`*

all these themes are css files installs by as part of primeng and you have two method to include these themes

angular.json

```js
"styles": [
                "src/styles.css",
                "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css", 
                "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
                "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css",
                "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
                "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css"
            ],
```

or by import the css file in global scss file

global.scss

```css
@import "primeicons/primeicons.css";
@import "primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
@import "primeng/resources/themes/nova-dark/theme.css";
```

these are the theme files inside the primeng packages

`primeng/resources/themes/**theme name**/theme.css`
[image]

Comment: I edited my original post including details because it seems to me that I have only few themes. Why?

Comment: yes previous  versions don't have that much of themes you can use the new version or wait until it fully release (primeng 10) the biggest update the new themes and better design

Comment: So do you think that I am using an old version of PrimeNG?

Comment: yes maybe you are using version 9 but you can update when the new version (10) released